# Loss and Accuracy remains is the same throught my training

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to run a simple feed forward neural network and my training and testing accuracy seems to be the same throughout the epochs.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import plot_model
from IPython import embed
from keras import optimizers
from keras import backend as K

import keras
import numpy as np
import glob


import pre_process_data as dataProc

def network():

    path = '/home/RD*'
    files = glob.glob(path)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(2048, input_shape=(10030,),name="dense_one"))
    model.add(Dense(2048,activation='softmax',name = "dense_two"))
    model.add(Dense(4,activation='tanh',name = "dense_three"))
    #model.add(Dense(4,activation = 'relu',name = "dense_four"))

    for l in model.layers:
            print l.name, l.input_shape , "=======>", l.output_shape

    print model.summary()

    model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer = "adam",
                  metrics = ['accuracy'])   

    #Reads data from text files 
    pre_proc_data = dataProc.OnlyBestuData()

    data = pre_proc_data[:,0:-1]
    labels = pre_proc_data[:, -1] 
    labels = np.random.randint(0,4,32)   #Generate random lables

    one_hot_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes=4)
    model.fit(x = data,y = one_hot_labels ,epochs = 10, batch_size = 2, verbose = 2)

    #embed()


def main():
        with K.get_session():
                network()

   main()
```

My output is pasted below. I am trying to learn how neural networks work and hence I wrote a very simple feed forward network. I have tried changing the optimizer from "adam" to "SGD" with learning rates of 0.01. Yet, my network gives me the constant loss and accuracy. Since this is a small network the dimensions of entire input is 32x10030 where each row is a set of joint positions.

Could you tell me what could be going wrong in here?

**Output:**

```
Epoch 1/10
5s - loss: 9.6919 - acc: 0.4375
Epoch 2/10
5s - loss: 9.5701 - acc: 0.4688
Epoch 3/10
5s - loss: 9.5701 - acc: 0.4688
Epoch 4/10
5s - loss: 9.5701 - acc: 0.4688
Epoch 5/10
5s - loss: 9.5701 - acc: 0.4688
Epoch 6/10
5s - loss: 9.5701 - acc: 0.4688
Epoch 7/10
5s - loss: 9.5701 - acc: 0.4688
Epoch 8/10
5s - loss: 9.5701 - acc: 0.4688
Epoch 9/10
5s - loss: 9.5701 - acc: 0.4688
Epoch 10/10
5s - loss: 9.5701 - acc: 0.4688
```

Comment: Why do you randomly generate your labels? And if it is just for testing – why don´t you stick to a common dataset in order to get a baseline?

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense. I will try this on a common baseline. Just wanted to make sure the skeleton of my code is right.

Comment: One more thing I notice: Your last layer should be set with softmax activation. ReLu doesn´t make sense there because it is the «deciding» layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your setup correctly you have 32 samples with 10030 features (aka joint positions) each. That is a lot of features and way too few samples.

Try to use more samples and at the same time reduce your features i.e. with PCA.

Why do you use different and unusual activations for every layer? Try to set all layers to ReLU (and the last layer to softmax) and start from there.

Comment: Yes.  I was pretty sure it was way too many samples. Since it is my first neural network, I wanted to make sure that I haven't missed any crucial part, although my layer activations are messed up.

Comment: Yeah! I see..will dimensionality reduction help here?

Comment: PCA is worth a try in this case in my opinion. This way you can set up a much simpler neural network that might train way faster with no significant loss in accuracy.